# How to import library in DartPad?

Tags: dart

I wrote the below code in [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/) and it return me this error:

> Error compiling to JavaScript: unsupported import:
>
> package:collection/collection.dart

```
import "package:collection/collection.dart";

main(List<String> args) {
  
  var data = [
    {"title": 'Avengers', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
    {"title": 'Creed', "release_date": '10/01/2019'},
    {"title": 'Jumanji', "release_date": '30/10/2019'},
  ];
  
  var newMap = groupBy(data, (obj) => 
                       (obj as dynamic)['release_date']
                      );
  print(newMap);
  
}
```

Is there any way to resolve it?

Comment: From [documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/dartpad): "DartPad supports dart:* libraries that work with web apps; it doesn’t support dart:io or libraries from packages. If you want to use dart:io, use the Dart SDK instead. If you want to use a package, get the SDK for a platform that the package supports."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After waiting... It seems that the issue has **solved** by the new update of [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/) website.

[image]

Comment: Many basic packages are still not supported (such `package:dio/dio.dart`),

Answer (score 14):

It appears that importing packages is not currently supported. There's an open issue request this here:

https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/901